# Nautilus Folders Turned Chinese

Tags: nautilus, chinese

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with GNOME Shell 3.4.  I've been having problems with language settings being changed to Chinese (i.imgur.com/GR2rn.png).  I have fixed the problem of menus and everything else being in Chinese to be modified back to US English by changing the language at the login prompt, and have tried to remedy the problem by editing /etc/default/locale, but am at a loss of how to change the folders from Chinese back to US English.  For example, when I browse through Nautilus some of my folders are in Chinese.  Any ideas?

Comment: Lord of Time, this worked.  I can't believe I overlooked such a simple solution.  Thank you!

Comment: Comment changed to be an answer, so it can be marked as the solution that worked.

Answer (score 2):

Those folders may be using chinese characters.  Try renaming them to something in English, to remove the special characters.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: I beg to disagree, it in and of itself is a solution.  see above in the comments on the question, @StephenMyall, as this was originally a comment which solved the user's issue.  I've rephrased the answer so it is actually an answer.