# Option Button in Keyboard Layout > Input Sources is not pressable

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, system-settings

I would like to set the <kbd>Caps-lock</kbd> key as a Compose key, which you do, as far as I remember, by pressing the "Options" Button in *Keyboard Layout > Input Sources*, and then enabling the appropriate option there.
That Button is not pressable though since I switched to 12.10. It did work in previous releases of Ubuntu.

gnome-control-center puts out these errors, when I click on Keyboard Layout:

> (gnome-control-center:3645): common-cc-panel-WARNING **: Could not find current language 'Л\u0003C!\u007f' in the treeview

> (gnome-control-center:3645): common-cc-panel-WARNING **: locale '"en_US.UTF-8"' isn't valid

I'm not sure if the errors are related though, maybe they are related to the "interface switching to chinese bug" which seems surprisingly widespread:

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/93910/language-changed-to-chinese-how-do-i-change-it-back

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/101282/language-support-has-an-unwanted-chinese-language-option

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/147805/nautilus-folders-turned-chinese

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/175643/desktop-12-04-gnome-cairo-suddenly-in-chinese

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/100684/unwanted-chinese-language-got-set-in-system-settings

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/152668/i-cannot-set-my-system-back-to-english-from-chinese-language

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/132347/gnome-classic-language-turned-into-chinese-how-do-i-change-it-back-to-english

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/185592/strange-display-language-in-gnome-shell

I'm not sure they are related to this bug, but I just wanted to mention it, maybe it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Option button is only available when you have added multiple input sources.

Edit:
I found a solution for adding compose key here:
http://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2012/09/21/input-sources-in-gnome/